# Grand Average in place of Grand Total in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

In a pivot table I want to change the Grand Total field to Grand Average. For example.

```
Row Labels   Day1   Day2   Day3   GrandTotal
1             10     20     30        60
2             15     25     35        75
3             20     30     40        90
```

And I want it to be like:

```
Row Labels   Day1   Day2   Day3   GrandTotal
1             10     20     30        20
2             15     25     35        25
3             20     30     40        30
```

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the cell where you want to show the average, select **Summarize Data By** and then click **Average**.

[image]

Comment: The 'Average' Selection is greyed out for me. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

**Do the followings:**

- In the **Pivot Table**, Right click on the 
  New Field's label cell, and click **Field 
  Settings**.
- Under **Subtotals**, hit **Custom**.
- Select the **Sum & Average** from 
  summary functions list to get the
  **Grand Average**.
- Finish with **Ok**.

*Now to remove the Grand Total,*

- Right-click on the Grand Total label cell & 
  Remove it.